# how to make another AccountPicture in the left side of the drawer header

Tags: flutter, layout, drawer

```
UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
          accountName: Text("xxx"),
          accountEmail: Text("flutterdev@gmail.com"),
          currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://img.icons8.com/pastel-glyph/2x/user-male.png'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent
          ),
        ),
```

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lyrm9.png)

how do i add another account picture on the left side like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkbnZ.png),
i've tried using the row column,but i think there is a more better way to do it.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `otherAccountsPictures`

```
otherAccountsPictures: [
      CircleAvatar(
        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
            'https://img.icons8.com/pastel-glyph/2x/user-male.png'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
    ],
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              accountName: Text("xxx"),
              accountEmail: Text("flutterdev@gmail.com"),
              currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                    'https://img.icons8.com/pastel-glyph/2x/user-male.png'),
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent),
              otherAccountsPictures: [
                CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                      'https://img.icons8.com/pastel-glyph/2x/user-male.png'),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            MediaQuery.removePadding(
              context: context,
              child: Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text('Item 1'),
                      onTap: () {
                        // Update the state of the app.
                        // ...
                      },
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text('Item 2'),
                      onTap: () {
                        // Update the state of the app.
                        // ...
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```